# R: long to wide with sequential matching pairs

Tags: r, transpose, tidyr, reshape2

I have data that looks like the following where **str** repeats 4 times in **grp**. The object is to transpose the **out** variable, to two columns, associated with sequential matching pairs of str.  For example, str "dat" at row 1 should match with row three.  Then we move onto str "axy" at row 2 matching with row nine.

Right now I'm assuming that to get started a new factor has to be generated, looping and coding for first and second instance of of each str, which I should be able to do provided there is an easy way to check for string match, however any alternative approach would be helpful.

```
Grp  str out
1    dat   45
1    axy   76
1    dat   55
1    bte   61
1    cny   41
1    bte   34
1    cny   67
1    dat   32
1    axy   59
1    cny   12
1    dat   51
1    cny   50
1    bte   52
1    axy   38
1    bte   17
1    axy   78
2 ....
```

The output would look like this, with 8 rows per Grp.

```
Grp  str1  out1 str2 out2
1    dat     45   dat    55
1    axy     76   axy    59
1    bte     61   bte    34
1    cny     41   cny    67
1    dat     32   dat    51
1    cny     12   cny    50
1    bte     52   bte    17
1    axy     38   axy    78
```

Or I guess like this,

```
Grp  str1  out1 out2
1    dat     45   55
1    axy     76   59
1    bte     61   34
1    cny     41   67
1    dat     32   51
1    cny     12   50
1    bte     52   17
1    axy     38   78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` and `lapply` fit good here:

```
foo <- lapply(split(df, df$str), function(x){
  x$ind <- rep(1:2, nrow(x)/2);
  x
})
foo <- do.call(rbind, foo)
foo <- split(foo[, -4], foo[,4])
foo <- data.frame(foo[[1]], foo[[2]])[, -c(4,5)]
names(foo)[c(3,4)] <- c("out1", "out2")
foo
       Grp str out1 out2
axy.2    1 axy   76   59
axy.14   1 axy   38   78
bte.4    1 bte   61   34
bte.13   1 bte   52   17
cny.5    1 cny   41   67
cny.10   1 cny   12   50
dat.1    1 dat   45   55
dat.8    1 dat   32   51
```

If you want the output to have the same row order as your desired output shown on your question, then try the following:

```
foo2 <- foo[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", rownames(foo)))), ]
rownames(foo2) <- NULL
foo2
  Grp str out1 out2
1   1 dat   45   55
2   1 axy   76   59
3   1 bte   61   34
4   1 cny   41   67
5   1 dat   32   51
6   1 cny   12   50
7   1 bte   52   17
8   1 axy   38   78
```

`df` is your data.frame:

```
df <- read.table(text="Grp  str out
1    dat   45
                 1    axy   76
                 1    dat   55
                 1    bte   61
                 1    cny   41
                 1    bte   34
                 1    cny   67
                 1    dat   32
                 1    axy   59
                 1    cny   12
                 1    dat   51
                 1    cny   50
                 1    bte   52
                 1    axy   38
                 1    bte   17
                 1    axy   78
                 ", header=TRUE)
```